# Is there a way to put the value of a javascript variable into an html paragraph in between regular text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kind of stuck on a little html / javascript thing that I'm working on. I am trying to make a hi - lo game and I'm trying to display the guessable range for the user. The code I am having trouble with looks like this:

rangeCheck.innerHTML = "The answer is within the range: `rangeLow` - `rangeHigh`";

rangecheck is a const variable in my javascript that changes the contents of an html paragraph.

rangeLow and rangeHigh are both regular "var" variables inside of my javascript and they contain a value for both the highest allowable guess and the lowest allowable guess.

I'm trying to have the paragraph line look something like this:

"The answer is within the range: 0 - 100"

Is this even possible and if so how would I go about doing it?

Comment: `is a const variable` I'll keep loving this

Comment: Basic string concatenation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#concatenating_strings

Comment: Your line of code is this? `rangeCheck.innerHTML = "The answer is within the range: \`rangeLow\` - \`rangeHigh\`";` (I think backticks have been interpreted as markdown formatting in your post)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation or string interpolation with template literals.

```js
rangeCheck.textContent = `The answer is within the range: ${rangeLow} - ${rangeHigh}`;
```